# difficulty with fibonacci function

Tags: java, fibonacci

I'm supposed to change this recursive function, into an iterative function...

```
int rFib(int n) 
{   //assumes n >= 0
    if(n <= 1)
        return n;
    else
        return (rFib(n-1) + rFib(n-2));
}
```

But I'm drawing a blank on the mathematical view of this... I would appreciate any assistance. I was able to get the other 3 functions, but I just can't seem to figure out the math of this one.

```
public static int fib(int n)
{
    int theFib = 1;
    while(n > 1)
    {
        theFib = n - 1;
        n = n + n - 2;         
}
        System.out.println(theFib);
        return theFib;
    }
```

Comment: have a look at http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/02/dynamic-programming-introduction.html based on dynamic programming

Comment: 'supposed to change this function'? Is this a homework question? its ok if it is, just be up front about it

Comment: for problems like these, i find it really helps to ignore the code completely at first, figure it out on paper or a whiteboard first. then after you know how it works, how would the code look? ie, you have two numbers, you add them together to get a third number, then use that number added to one of your first numbers to get a fourth number. then what happens? when do you stop adding together?

Comment: thanks for all the assistance you guys. and yeah, this is hw...I didn't think of having to save the numbers. much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The next number in the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) is the sum of the last two numbers, so you'll need to remember the last two numbers.

In pseudo code, since you should do some of the homework yourself:

```
n1 = 0
n2 = 1
loop
    n = n1 + n2
    n1 = n2
    n2 = n
end loop
```

I'll leave it to you to limit the looping.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example [here](http://en.literateprograms.org/Fibonacci_numbers_(Java)#Iteration).

The code in question:

```
public class FibonacciIterative {
    public static int fib(int n) {
                int prev1=0, prev2=1;
                for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                    int savePrev1 = prev1;
                    prev1 = prev2;
                    prev2 = savePrev1 + prev2;
                }
                return prev1;
    }
}
```

It does not really matter which direction (up or down) you count. The challenge is to deal with the limits properly.

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic programming technique:

```
    static int fib(int n) {
        int[] fibs = new int[n + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            if (i <= 1) {
                fibs[i] = i;
            } else {
                fibs[i] = fibs[i - 1] + fibs[i - 2];
            }
        }
        return fibs[n];
    }
```